# How to retrive all hard disk space

Tags: windows

I have installed and un-installed ubuntu a lot of time in my windows machine by creating new partitions now the machine is showing less amount of hard disk space. And less number of hard disk partition in windows-7 i accessed it using computer management in windows . now what i want to do is that i want to recombine all of the available space of windows machine. and to reinstall ubuntu over windows. i am not getting any idea how to do that?. when i am trying to install ubuntu it is showing a small amount of hard disk space.

Answer (score 1):

If you have backed up all your important data, then just delete all the partitions, and in the Ubuntu installer, choose to use the full disk for the Ubuntu install.

Comment: is there any other way apart from this?